# configure squid3 as transparent proxy

Tags: squid

After adding this lines to the file `squid.conf`:

```
httpd_accel_host virtual
httpd_accel_port 80
httpd_accel_with_proxy  on
httpd_accel_uses_host_header on
```

I'm having this error message:

```
* Restarting Squid HTTP Proxy 3.0 squid3                                       2013/05/12 20:33:57| cache_cf.cc(346) squid.conf:59 unrecognized: 'httpd_accel_with_proxy'
2013/05/12 20:33:57| cache_cf.cc(346) squid.conf:60 unrecognized 'httpd_accel_uses_host_header'
2013/05/12 20:33:57| cache_cf.cc(346) squid.conf:61 unrecognized: 'httpd_accel_host'
2013/05/12 20:33:57| cache_cf.cc(346) squid.conf:62 unrecognized: 'httpd_accel_port'
```

how can i resolve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was a change in squid config option after version 2.6, replace that with :

```
http_port 3128 transparent
http_port 80 vhost
```

Comment: Should it be updated with 'intercept'? https://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/Intercept/LinuxRedirect

Comment: I don't think an 8 year answer should be updated with anything

Answer (score 3):

In squid versions 3.1 and up, the directive is: `http_port 80 intercept`.  In versions 2.6 up to and not including 3.1, it's `http_port 80 transparent`.  The intercept or transparent option tells squid to infer the proxy destination from the `Host:` header as with `httpd_accel_uses_host_header`.