# How to configure squid4 as transparent proxy?

Tags: linux, iptables, squid, transparent-proxy, web-proxy

There are many posts how to do that, most for older versions.

According to this [post](https://serverfault.com/questions/507124/configure-squid3-as-transparent-proxy/507128), to setup squid as transparent server for port 80 it should be as simple as this:

```
//squid.config
http_port 3128 transparent
http_port 80 accel #vhost option is deprecated
http_port 443 accel #not forget https
```

but can't put it to work. i can't figure out if is my ip tables configuration, or the squid configuration.

Squid runs on the same pc as the gateway and dhcp server.

The iptables configuration:

```
# Generated by xtables-save v1.8.2 on Sun Feb  2 14:05:24 2020
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [512813:147258305]
:INPUT ACCEPT [505693:146550975]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [5559:319150]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [485369:200427691]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [486362:200704832]
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Feb  2 14:05:24 2020
# Generated by xtables-save v1.8.2 on Sun Feb  2 14:05:24 2020
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [505677:146546207]
:FORWARD DROP [5532:317382]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [485351:200422918]
-A FORWARD -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -p tcp -m tcp --dport 110 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -p tcp -m tcp --dport 993 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -p icmp -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Feb  2 14:05:24 2020
# Generated by xtables-save v1.8.2 on Sun Feb  2 14:05:24 2020
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [55608:3516287]
:INPUT ACCEPT [48615:2816337]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [4525:272304]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [17086:1270605]
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3128
-A PREROUTING -i wlan0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.1.1.0:3128
-A PREROUTING -i wlan0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3128
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
```

The squid.config file:

```
acl LocalNet src 192.168.4.0/24 #my network . 
http_access allow LocalNet

acl localnet src 0.0.0.1-0.255.255.255
#acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8
#acl localnet src 100.64.0.0/10
#acl localnet src 169.254.0.0/16
#acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12
#acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16
acl localnet src fc00::/7
acl localnet src fe80::/10
acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80  #http
acl Safe_ports port 21  #ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443 #https
acl Safe_ports port 70  #gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210 #wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  #unregisted ports
acl Safe_ports port 280 #http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488 #gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591 #filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777 #multilining http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT
http_access deny !Safe_ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager
#include /etc/squid/conf.d/*
http_access allow localhost
http_access allow all

#for explicit proxy
#http_port 3128
#http_port 3129 tproxy

#for transparent proxy
http_port 3128 transparent
http_port 80 accel
http_port 443 accel

#cache
cache_dir ufs /var/spool/squid 100 16 256
coredump_dir /var/spool/squid
refresh_pattern ^ftp:           1440    20%     10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:        1440    0%      1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0     0%      0
refresh_pattern .               0       20%     4320
cache_effective_user proxy
cache_effective_group proxy

#log file
logformat timeread %tl %6tr %>a %Ss/%03Hs %<st %rm %ru %un %Sh/%<A %mt
access_log daemon:/var/log/squid/access.log timeread
```

The squid start log:

```
squid[23403]: Starting Squid Cache version 4.6 for arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf...
squid[23403]: Service Name: squid
squid[23403]: Process ID 23403
squid[23403]: Process Roles: worker
squid[23403]: With 1024 file descriptors available
squid[23403]: Initializing IP Cache...
squid[23403]: DNS Socket created at [::], FD 5
squid[23403]: DNS Socket created at 0.0.0.0, FD 9
squid[23403]: Adding domain Home from /etc/resolv.conf
squid[23403]: Adding nameserver 192.168.1.254 from /etc/resolv.conf
squid[23403]: Logfile: opening log daemon:/var/log/squid/access.log
squid[23403]: Logfile Daemon: opening log /var/log/squid/access.log
squid[23403]: Unlinkd pipe opened on FD 15
squid[23403]: Local cache digest enabled; rebuild/rewrite every 3600/3600 sec
squid[23403]: Store logging disabled
squid[23403]: Swap maxSize 102400 + 262144 KB, estimated 28041 objects
squid[23403]: Target number of buckets: 1402
squid[23403]: Using 8192 Store buckets
squid[23403]: Max Mem  size: 262144 KB
squid[23403]: Max Swap size: 102400 KB
squid[23403]: Rebuilding storage in /var/spool/squid (clean log)
squid[23403]: Using Least Load store dir selection
squid[23403]: Set Current Directory to /var/spool/squid
squid[23403]: Finished loading MIME types and icons.
squid[23403]: HTCP Disabled.
squid[23403]: Pinger socket opened on FD 22
squid[23403]: Squid plugin modules loaded: 0
squid[23403]: Adaptation support is off.
squid[23403]: Accepting NAT intercepted HTTP Socket connections at local=[::]:3128 remote=[::] FD 18 flags=41
squid[23403]: Accepting reverse-proxy HTTP Socket connections at local=[::]:80 remote=[::] FD 19 flags=9
squid[23403]: Accepting reverse-proxy HTTP Socket connections at local=[::]:443 remote=[::] FD 20 flags=9
squid[23403]: Done reading /var/spool/squid swaplog (0 entries)
squid[23403]: Store rebuilding is 0.00% complete
squid[23403]: Finished rebuilding storage from disk.
squid[23403]:         0 Entries scanned
squid[23403]:         0 Invalid entries.
squid[23403]:         0 With invalid flags.
squid[23403]:         0 Objects loaded.
squid[23403]:         0 Objects expired.
squid[23403]:         0 Objects cancelled.
squid[23403]:         0 Duplicate URLs purged.
squid[23403]:         0 Swapfile clashes avoided.
squid[23403]:   Took 0.05 seconds (  0.00 objects/sec).
squid[23403]: Beginning Validation Procedure
squid[23403]:   Completed Validation Procedure
squid[23403]:   Validated 0 Entries
squid[23403]:   store_swap_size = 0.00 KB
squid[23403]: storeLateRelease: released 0 objects
```

**Update**

iptables configuration update below, according to @Piotr P. Karwasz. Also i add log that can be see at /var/log/messages.

```
# Generated by xtables-save v1.8.2 on Wed Feb  5 18:05:20 2020
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [26643:2488050]
:INPUT ACCEPT [26417:2421007]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [203:57945]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [46685:14572738]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [47031:14661263]
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Feb  5 18:05:20 2020
# Generated by xtables-save v1.8.2 on Wed Feb  5 18:05:20 2020
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [26404:2417368]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [7:448]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [46671:14569146]
-A INPUT -j LOG
-A FORWARD -j LOG
-A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -j LOG
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Feb  5 18:05:20 2020
# Generated by xtables-save v1.8.2 on Wed Feb  5 18:05:20 2020
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [612:69658]
:INPUT ACCEPT [577:59792]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [26:2979]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [543:44473]
-A PREROUTING -j LOG
-A PREROUTING -i wlan0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3128
-A POSTROUTING -j LOG
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
-A OUTPUT -j LOG
-A OUTPUT -o lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3128
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Feb  5 18:05:20 2020
# Warning: iptables-legacy tables present, use iptables-legacy-save to see them
```

For clarity, here the command i use to filter for dns query hits:

```
tail -f /var/log/messages |grep -wi --color  -w 'UDP.*DPT=53'
```

**Update 2**

Bind 9 was blocking the dns querys. even stoped. Guess is not a regular service. I changed bind9 settings to allow dns querys from anyplace.

Now i got hits like this on the log, for port 53:

```
Feb  5 18:36:43 MyLinuxBox kernel: [11771.211903] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=b8:27:eb:35:e4:5b:48:43:7c:04:7e:55:08:00 SRC=192.168.42.19 DST=192.168.42.1 LEN=59 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=255 ID=43761 PROTO=UDP SPT=63906 DPT=5
```

It seams the dns query pass through the linux-box, from wlan0 to eth0, as is supposed too, but the response doesn't reach the client, resulting in a dns query timeout.

It is possible bind9 is still messing with the query.

Comment: Which of your network interfaces is the external one (the one with a public IP)? If you are testing on the same machine as the router, the `PREROUTING` chain will never be hit.

Comment: The eth0 has the public ip. Squid runs o a pc that as the 2 interfaces and routes traffic through him. The linux box should work as an hotspot.

Comment: Your WiFi clients are using Bind9 as their `DNS` server (the `DHCP` server provides the configuration). Therefore you need to set `allow-recursion { localhost; 192.168.42.0/24; };` in the `options` section of Bind's config and keep it running. If everything passes through Bind, there is no need to accept `DNS` traffic in the `FORWARD` chain.

Answer (score 2):

Your **iptables** **nat** table should look like this:

```
-A OUTPUT -o lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3128
-A PREROUTING -i wlan0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3128
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

This way both the **web** traffic from the wireless network and the machine itself will be sent to Squid. No masquerading is needed when sending packets to the `wlan0` interface.

With a working Squid you can also delete the rule:

```
-A FORWARD -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

in the **filter** table.

**Edit:** Your `DNS` resolution problem comes from the restrictive `FORWARD` policy you have. At first you might start by allowing all outgoing traffic and the return packets:

```
-A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

and **only** when you know what kind of services you need, replace the **second** rule with more specific ones, e.g.:

```
-A FORWARD -o eth0 -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type echo-request -m comment --comment ping -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -m comment --comment DNS -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -m comment --comment DNS -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o eth0 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 25,465,587 -m comment --comment SMTP -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o eth0 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 110,995 -m comment --comment POP3 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o eth0 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 143,993 -m comment --comment IMAP -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: can't put it to work with this configuration too. Squid is blocking the way, with access denied. Yet, if i send the traffic to port 3128, by setting proxy manually, it works.

Comment: Sorry, the `OUTPUT` rule I gave previously causes a redirection loop. It should be fixed now (with the `-o lo` option).

Comment: It works, but dns query won't pass througth.I can only get sites by ip.

Comment: Yes, the devices on your WiFi network must be allowed to query a DNS server (port 53 of both udp and tcp), unless you install a `DNS` resolver like **unbound** on the router. I edited the answer with some details.

Comment: I clear all rules, changed every default to accept, add the rules you mention. Still didn't work, so i stop the squid but still not working. I added log to every rule and then look for UDP packets on port 53. I only see hits coming from the localhost. i will update the post

Comment: Made some progress. Somehow the bind9 service was blocking requests that come from the wlan0. When i set allow dns query from any place, requests start to appear on eth0, coming from wlan0. But still got dns timeout, so i thing the responses is not going back to the sender.. i will post details on question again.

Answer (score 1):

If your Squid proxy runs on your gateway, you would need the following iptables to redirect the traffic on HTTP/HTTPS to Squid (note here ens33 is the NIC facing the local network), see complete tutorial at https://docs.diladele.com/tutorials/transparent_proxy_debian/final.html.

```
# redirect HTTP to locally installed Squid instance
-A PREROUTING -i ens33 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3126

# redirect HTTPS to locally installed Squid instance
-A PREROUTING -i ens33 -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3127
```

If you need to run your Squid on a *separate* box than your router/gateway, you'd need to use policy based routing, see tutorial at https://docs.diladele.com/tutorials/policy_based_routing_squid/index.html.